# Keep cursor in fugitive-:Gstatus window when view diffs/splits

Tags: key-bindings, vim-windows, plugin-fugitive

I have tried to attach to following fugitive mapping:

```
nnoremap <buffer> <silent> D :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<CR>
```

a `:h window-move-cursor` mapping:

```diff
diff --git a/plugin/fugitive.vim b/plugin/fugitive.vim
index 805518a..897295a 100644
--- a/plugin/fugitive.vim
+++ b/plugin/fugitive.vim
@@ -2552,8 +2552,8 @@ function! s:BufReadIndex() abort
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> cc :<C-U>Gcommit<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> cva :<C-U>Gcommit --amend --verbose<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> cvc :<C-U>Gcommit --verbose<CR>
-    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> D :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<CR>
-    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dd :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<CR>
+    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> D :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<Bar>exe "normal \<C-w>P"<CR>
+    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dd :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<Bar>exe "normal \<C-w>P"<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dh :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gsdiff')<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> ds :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gsdiff')<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dp :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiffEdit()<CR>
```

However, it does not work.

Note, the `:h fugitive-:Gstatus` window is a preview window which is supposed to be unique.

Related issues on github are

- *[#132 – Easy way to move between diffs (Unimpaired-style)](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/132)*
- *[#339 - Preview changes from Gstatus](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/339)*
- *[#476 - Gdiff without focus change in Gstatus](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive/issues/476)*

Comment: I don't know if it will help, but I think you should protect `<C-w>` with the keycode `<lt>`. So your 2nd mapping could be:             `nnoremap <buffer> <silent> D :<C-U>exe <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<Bar>exe "normal! \<lt>C-w>P"<CR>` Otherwise `<C-w>` will be translated into a literal `^W` which on the command-line deletes the previous word.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, it does not help. I think the backslash does already protect the `<C-w>` key sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer by Peter Rincker.

Using `feedkeys` works in contrast to attaching the mapping `\<C-w>P` via `<Bar> normal`.

Problem with the answer by Peter Rincker:
Fugitive defines mappings on the fly based on different events which override occasionally the mappings set up by the event `BufEnter`. I couldn't figure out which events I would have to add to Peter Rinckers answer to retain the extended mappings.

A simple way to circumvent this problem is to directly modify the mappings in fugitive:

```diff
$ git diff
diff --git a/plugin/fugitive.vim b/plugin/fugitive.vim
index 805518a..f0120f8 100644
--- a/plugin/fugitive.vim
+++ b/plugin/fugitive.vim
@@ -14,6 +14,10 @@ endif

 " Section: Utility

+function! s:focus_preview()
+  call feedkeys("\<c-w>P")
+endfunction
+
 function! s:function(name) abort
   return function(substitute(a:name,'^s:',matchstr(expand('<sfile>'), '<SNR>\d\+_'),''))
 endfunction
@@ -2552,12 +2556,12 @@ function! s:BufReadIndex() abort
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> cc :<C-U>Gcommit<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> cva :<C-U>Gcommit --amend --verbose<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> cvc :<C-U>Gcommit --verbose<CR>
-    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> D :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<CR>
-    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dd :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<CR>
-    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dh :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gsdiff')<CR>
-    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> ds :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gsdiff')<CR>
-    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dp :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiffEdit()<CR>
-    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dv :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gvdiff')<CR>
+    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> D :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<Bar>exe <SID>focus_preview()<CR>
+    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dd :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gdiff')<Bar>exe <SID>focus_preview()<CR>
+    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dh :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gsdiff')<Bar>exe <SID>focus_preview()<CR>
+    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> ds :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gsdiff')<Bar>exe <SID>focus_preview()<CR>
+    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dp :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiffEdit()<Bar>exe <SID>focus_preview()<CR>
+    nnoremap <buffer> <silent> dv :<C-U>execute <SID>StageDiff('Gvdiff')<Bar>exe <SID>focus_preview()<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> p :<C-U>execute <SID>StagePatch(line('.'),line('.')+v:count1-1)<CR>
     xnoremap <buffer> <silent> p :<C-U>execute <SID>StagePatch(line("'<"),line("'>"))<CR>
     nnoremap <buffer> <silent> P :<C-U>execute <SID>StagePatch(line('.'),line('.')+v:count1-1)<CR>
```

Of course, they will be overwritten if you pull in a new version of fugitive.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I came up with to put in your `~/.vimrc`:

```vim
augroup vimrc_fugitive_status
  autocmd!
  autocmd BufEnter index if get(b:, 'fugitive_type') == 'index' | call <SID>fugitive_status_mappings() | endif
augroup END

function! s:fugitive_status_mappings()
  if get(b:, 'status_mappings', 0) == 0
    call s:map_with_preview('dd', 'n')
    call s:map_with_preview('D', 'n')
  endif
  let b:status_mappings = 1
endfunction

function! s:map_with_preview(map, mode)
  call s:update_maping(a:map, a:mode, 'v:val . ":call <SID>focus_preview()\<cr>"') 
endfunction

function! s:focus_preview()
  call feedkeys("\<c-w>P")
endfunction

function! s:update_maping(map, mode, expr)
  let map = maparg(a:map, a:mode, 0, 1)
  execute a:mode .
        \ (map.noremap ? 'noremap ' : 'map ') .
        \ (map.buffer ? '<buffer> ' : '') .
        \ (map.silent ? '<silent> ' : '') .
        \ (map.expr ? '<expr> ' : '') .
        \ (map.nowait ? '<nowait> ' : '') .
        \ map.lhs . ' ' .
        \ map([substitute(map.rhs, '<SID>', '<SNR>' . map.sid. '_', 'g')], a:expr)[0]
endfunction
```

The basic idea is to capture the old mapping with `maparg()` and then issue `<c-w>P` with `feedkeys()` after executing the old mapping.

This is a non-trivial solution due to the following issues:

- Fugitive does not supply `<Plug>` mappings for the status window mappings so we must use `maparg()`
- Due to the way the `autocmd`'s fire we must use an event like `BufEnter` in lieu of the `FileType` event
- `feedkeys()` is tricky inside mappings due to proper escaping so use function call instead

There may very well be a more concise and/or better solution to altering `:Gstatus` mappings, but I am unsure how to properly do so.

To add more mappings simply add more lines like so to `s:fugitve_status_mappings` function:

```
call s:map_with_preview('ds', 'n')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. However, I wouldn't mind to modify fugitive itself.

Comment: For some reason, it does not work for `dp`. I have added this as you have suggested. Any idea why this is different to `dd/D`? I just noticed your solution does not work for all mappings reliable. There is something different to you.

Comment: Are you aware that fugitive already defines an augroup with the same name as you have picked: `augroup fugitive_status`. Fugitives and your augroup follow the common pattern to delete all autocmds of this group with `autocmd!`. I could resolve my issue by renaming your augroup to `augroup fugitive_status_update_mappings`.

Comment: No, it still does not work reliable. Using `dd`, `dp` and `dd` in a row will make the cursor to jump to the first window not remaining in the preview window of :Gstatus. Can you reproduce this?

Comment: I was not aware that fugitive uses that autogroup name. Please change it. You can certainly modify fugitive itself. However you will probably have to rebase your changes after you update fugitive. e.g. `git pull --rebase`. As for the mappings not being reliable I assume there is some race condition with how `feedkeys()` is being used by fugitive. Normally I avoid using `feedkeys()` except as a last resort due its tricky nature.